# I am doing a technology that is Java RESTful Web Service Jersey & jdbc with MySQL. Can I send multiple row data together?

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I'm at my learning stages and I am working on a project in which I am doing a technology that is Java RestFul Web Service Jersey & JDBC with MySQL. Can I send multiple row data together? & as a same flipkart invoice receipt codeing & many item add my receipt

Comment: Where do you want to send data? in data base or in http request

Comment: @Mahesh Sain, In that case, I would like to recommend you read some document on rest full web service.
Here are some Links you can start

1) [simple crud example](https://o7planning.org/en/11207/simple-crud-example-with-java-restful-web-service)

2) [Build RESTful Web services and dynamic Web applications with the multi-tier architecture](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-multitier2/index.html)